# Test for if you're on 1st page of paginated post (with nextpage quicktag)

Tags: pagination, nextpage

I'm developing a site that involves a lot of long posts I'd like to break up using the nextpage quicktag. On the first page there's a large splash photo in the header that I'd like to disappear on subsequent pages—so I need some way of testing if the user is on the first page. I did find this code:

`if ( isset($wp_query->query_vars['page'] ) )`

But that seems to only works with default permalink settings. I need something that works with the Postname permalink setting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @s_ha_dum, you can check the value of `page`. The value is 1 when you're on the first page.

```
global $page;
if ( $page == 1 ) :
    // you're on the first page
endif;
```

But probably you need to check if the post is paginated first:

```
global $multipage;
if ( 0 !== $multipage ) :

    global $page;
    if ( $page == 1 ) :
        // you're on the first page
    endif;

endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your code doesn't work, but you should be able to check the `page` `global`. It should be a positive number on all but first page of a pages post. `$page` is `NULL` on the first page but set to an integer otherwise. The following should work, and does when I test it.

```
global $page;
if (empty ($page)) {
    echo 'first page';
}
```

... should work.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work.

Comment: This code is correct. I just tested it. If it is not working for you then something is breaking it. I don't know how to guess what.